# Unable to apply colorfilter in Android?

Tags: imageview, colorfilter

I am trying to give my image a clicking effect in Android Studio. The idea is that a color filter is applied when you press the button, and then the color filter gets cleared after they release the button.

I have tried doing this by using a switch statement using hte OnTouch method, however when I open the app it just crashes.

Here's my code:

```
{
    final ImageView DNIcon_id = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DNIcon_id);
    DNIcon_id.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            sp.play(DN_id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS): {

                    DNIcon_id.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
                    break;
                }
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE): {
                    DNIcon_id.clearColorFilter();
                    break;
                }

            }
            return true;


        }

    });
}
}
```

If you know what I am doing wrong, please tell me. I would really appreciate it.

Sincerely,

Vidal

Comment: There is a feature that does this automatically for you. Read up on Color State Lists - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

add this to res/values/colors.xml

```
<color name="opaque">#90FFFFFF</color>
```

make res/drawable/overlay.xml and put this in it

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/opaque" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

here is an example of how to use it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image_here"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/overlay"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Note on the color:**

You can change the '90' in the color to make it more or less opaque. Keep in mind, it is hexadecimal, so full opacity would be 'FF'. Also, this solution assumes that you are using #FFFFFF as your window background in your app. The last 6 digits of the "opaque" color should be whatever you are using as your window background.